# How do high-quality antiviruses recognize viruses?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

How do high-quality antiviruses recognize viruses? I heard that such programs use virus databases. How high quality can an antivirus that uses free databases be, which databases are the best among those that are in the public domain?

Comment: High-quality anti-virus programs tend to keep their virus signature databases proprietary.

Comment: This post is a collection of different questions, but they have all been asked here before.